# Russian SE Community FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq

## (Under construction!)

С переводом на русский язык.

> **Note** - **Внимание**
>
> - You may also wish to review [the community FAQ for all sites in the StackExchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).
>     (Кроме этого поста, см. также часто задаваемые вопросы, излагающие правила, общие для всех сайтов в сети StackExchange.)
> - You can add questions to this FAQ. In order to see *how*, check the bottom of this question.
>     (Вы можете добавлять вопросы к этому посту. В конце списка вопросов мы объясним, как это можно делать.)

### Content - Содержание

### About the site - О сайте

- How can we promote Russian StackExchange?
  Как помочь сделать сайт более популярным?
- What is this Community Bulletin?
  Что такое Community Bulletin?
- Can I propose a change in the FAQ?
  Могу ли я предложить изменить эти правила?

### Asking questions - О том, как задавать вопросы

- [What is considered on-topic and off-topic?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)
  Какие вопросы приветствуются на сайте? Какие вопросы считаются оффтопом?
- Should we restrict this site to academic questions only, or target a more casual audience?
  Я не специалист по языку, могу ли я задать вопрос?
- Do questions have to be answerable?
  Могу ли я задать вопрос, на который трудно или вообще невозможно ответить?

### Answering questions - О том, как отвечать

- Should answers be cited? How?
  Нужно ли цитировать ответы? Как?
- Should this site be restricted to academic answers only?
  Я не специалист по языку, могу ли я отвечать на вопросы?
- [Should I post a new answer to a question that already has an accepted answer?](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/71)
  Могу ли я ответить на вопрос, у которого уже есть ответ, засчитанный как правильный?

### Accepting answers - О том, как выбрать правильный ответ

- What are the criteria for marking an answer correct?
  Что такое правильный ответ?
- Can I change my accepted answer?
  Я засчитал один ответ как правильный. Могу ли я поменять свое решение?
- My answer was marked correct, now the OP changed it and chose another one: what's happening?
  Автор вопроса засчитал мой ответ, а потом передумал. В чем дело?
- Is it important that I accept an answer also in the Meta site? Why?
  Почему важно выбирать правильный ответ у вопросов с мета-сайта?
- What is the acceptance rate for questions?
  Что такое acceptance rate? Как часто другие люди выбирают правильные ответы для своих вопросов?

### Working with posts - О том, как редактировать вопросы и ответы

- I've got edit privileges! Now what?
  У меня есть привилегия, дающая право редактировать посты. Что мне с ней делать?

### Comments and discussions - О комментариях и обсуждениях

- What are comments for?
  Зачем нужны комментарии?
- How to handle discussions?
  Где я могу обсудить вопрос или ответ с его автором?
- Why was my comment deleted?
  Почему мой комментарий удалили?

### Tagging - О тэгах

- How should we tag questions?
  Зачем помечать вопросы тэгами?

### Reputation, badges, and voting - Репутация, медали и голосование

- [What is reputation and what is it for?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)
  Что такое репутация и зачем она нужна?
- Why was my question down-voted in Meta if nothing was wrong with it?
  Почему кто-то проголосовал против моего вопроса на мета-сайте, хотя с ним все было в порядке?

### Moderation and closing questions - Модерация и закрытие вопросов

- Who are the moderators? See also Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement
  Кто такие модераторы? См. также Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement
- I'm not a moderator, what does it mean to vote to close a question?
  Я не модератор, но могу закрывать вопросы. Когда и зачем это делать?
- My question was closed, in my opinion wrongly. What do I do?
  Я считаю, что мой вопрос закрыли безосновательно. Что мне делать?
- [I need to consult a moderator. Can I do it directly?](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/268/71)
  Мне нужна консультация модератора. Как её получить?

### External links - Ссылки на другие важные вопросы

Original links from meta.SO's community FAQ for sites in the StackExchange 2.0 network
(Ссылки на некоторые часто задаваемые вопросы с мета-сайта сообщества StackOverflow):

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)
- [How to Ask by Jon Skeet](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202)
- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Rubber Duck problem solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)

---

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ? - Как добавить вопрос к этому посту?

- Ask a new question on Meta. State it plainly and simply.
  Задайте новый вопрос на мета-сайте. Сформулируйте свой вопрос, и чем проще и яснее, тем лучше.
- If you want to propose an answer, do it later by using **Post your answer** button. Do not insert the answer in the question body.
  Если вы хотите сразу предложить ответ на свой вопрос, то не включайте его в тело вопроса. Ответьте при помощи кнопки **Post your answer**.
- **Link back** your question to this index. Paste this at the end of the question.
  В конце своего вопроса вставьте ссылку на этот пост:

  `[Return to FAQ index / Обратно к списку вопросов](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/71)`
- Tag your as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems to hit a mature state, flag it for moderator attention, choose **other** then write why you're flagging, and it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
  Добавьте к вопросу тэги [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) и [support](/questions/tagged/support). Когда ваш вопрос будет отвечен, привлеките к нему внимание модеатора, используя flag -> other и напишите в поле, что вопрос готов для включения в FAQ. Модераторы заметят и добавят тэг [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).
- Flag your question for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
  Создавая вопрос, попросите модератора добавить его в **community wiki**. Все вопросы про FAQ должны быть туда добавлены.
- Add a link in the above table of contents.
  Вставьте ссылку на свой вопрос в этот пост.

Answer (score 1):

**Some notes**:

- Please help me provide a Russian translation below the questions above so that we have a bilingual FAQ (it will be available to both Russian and International audience).
- When a question is posted and added here, it'd be good if you helped us translate those questions too.

For any comments, feel free to comment under this answer.

Comment: I do not understand: what's the difference between this and http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/faq?

Comment: @texnic This is the Main/whole site FAQ, not the Meta one. Here we are going to be more detailed and we'll be also adding the Russian translations.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understand. You see: too many FAQs---and a user is lost :D No, seriously, let's try to make less important texts, or people won't read it (they already don't).

Comment: So, do I understand now correctly that here you want to re-write the http://russian.stackexchange.com/faq?

Comment: @texnic Not exactly. Come to chat, I'll explain better. :)