# Should I post a new answer to a question that already has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, faq

If I see a question that has an accepted answer, should/can I answer?

(An accepted answer has a green tick next to it, as on the example figure below.)

---

Если вопрос, на который я хочу ответить, уже имеет принятый ответ, можно/нужно ли мне отвечать?

(Напротив принятых ответов стоит зеленая «галочка», как показано на рисунке внизу.)

> [image: An accepted answer | Ответ, который выбран в качестве правильного]

[Return to FAQ index / Обратно к списку вопросов](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/71)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**.

You can post it and if you think your answer might be *better*, *more detailed*, or *more up-to-date* then you should.

Don't let yourself discourage by the accepted answer. That can be changed. If you provide a new answer to an old question, which has **more detail**, it's **better formatted**, it **provides sources, cites references** and has a clear explanation, then it's likely that the OP (Original Poster) will change the accepted answer and choose yours.

In some cases, this might even bring a bounty to your answer, so what do you have to lose? Since you don't need to hurry, work on your answer, fix it, improve the wording and then submit it!

---

**Да.**

Отвечать можно, а если вы считаете, что ваш ответ может быть *лучше*, *полнее* или *содержит наиболее актуальную информацию*, вам даже следует дать свой ответ несмотря на то, что один из других ответов на вопрос уже засчитан как правильный.

Не отчаивайтесь, когда вы видите, что чей-то ответ уже принят автором вопроса. Это может измениться. Если вы дадите ответ, который **подробнее**, **лучше отформатирован**, **ссылается на достоверные источники** и чётко объясняет, что к чему, то вполне вероятно, что автор вопроса поменяет свое мнение и выберет ваш ответ вместо ответа другого человека.

Кроме того, раз уж вы отвечаете на вопрос, который был задан уже давно, не торопитесь, поработайте как следует над своим ответом и только затем выкладывайте его на сайт.

Comment: It is also worthwhile mentioning that the up-votes for an answer eventually can bring much more reputation than a mere acceptance (3 up-votes cost more than 1 accept).

Comment: @texnic Yes but the point of this question is to prove that accepted answers shouldn't discourage any user from answering. It doesn't treat about what you said, although it's certainly a valid point.