# I need to consult a moderator. Can I do it directly?

Tags: support, faq

I have questions I need to ask to moderators but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible? If yes, how?

[Return to FAQ index / Обратно к списку вопросов](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/71)

Answer (score 1):

Stackexchange sites don't have a Private Message system. You either use chat or send emails. Private emails are not the best for doing such things so what remains is chat.

What can you do? We created a room for this type of matter, [Ask a Russian Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6466/ask-a-russian-moderator). Please note that it's advisable you use this room for non-private matters.

If something more urgent and private occurs, consider emailing the Team by using the link at the bottom of the page.